# Does Python have an equivalent to Haskell's 'mask' or 'bracket' functions?

Tags: python, haskell, asynchronous, exception

In Haskell we have asynchronous exceptions; we can use [`throwTo`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/base-4.9.0.0/Control-Concurrent.html#v:throwTo) to raise any exception in another thread:

> ```
> throwTo :: Exception e => ThreadId -> e -> IO ()
> ```
>
> `throwTo` raises an arbitrary exception in the target thread (GHC only).

To be able to write code with guarantees like "will always release a lock after acquiring it", we have [`mask`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/base-4.9.0.0/Control-Exception.html#v:mask) to run code in which asynchronous exceptions may only be received while the computation is blocking:

> ```
> mask :: ((forall a. IO a -> IO a) -> IO b) -> IO b
> ```
>
> Executes an IO computation with asynchronous exceptions *masked*. That is, any thread which attempts to raise an exception in the current thread with `throwTo` will be blocked until asynchronous exceptions are unmasked again.

and a stronger [`uninterruptibleMask`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/base-4.9.0.0/Control-Exception.html#v:uninterruptibleMask) in which async exceptions will not be raised *at all* during a masked computation:

> ```
> uninterruptibleMask :: ((forall a. IO a -> IO a) -> IO b) -> IO b
> ```
>
> Like `mask`, but the masked computation is not interruptible

Masking is used to implement higher-level abstractions like [`bracket`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/base-4.9.0.0/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket):

> ```
> bracket
>     :: IO a         -- computation to run first ("acquire resource")
>     -> (a -> IO b)  -- computation to run last ("release resource")
>     -> (a -> IO c)  -- computation to run in-between
>     -> IO c         -- returns the value from the in-between computation
> ```
>
> When you want to acquire a resource, do some work with it, and then release the resource, it is a good idea to use `bracket`, because `bracket` will install the necessary exception handler to release the resource in the event that an exception is raised during the computation. If an exception is raised, then `bracket` will re-raise the exception (after performing the release).

If I understand correctly, Python has a (less general) form of asynchronous exceptions, with the most notable manifestation being [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt):

> Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly.

The documentation is imprecise about when the "check for interrupts" may occur, but it seems to imply that a `KeyboardInterrupt` may be raised at *any* point in a program's execution. So it seems, then, that Python's async exceptions come with all the same subtle difficulties of maintaining correctness.

For example, consider a pattern like this:

```
x = None
try:
    x = acquire()
    do_something(x)    # (1)
finally:
    if x is not None:  # (2)
        release(x)
```

If any exception is raised during `(1)`, then we are assured that the contents of the [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally) block will be executed. But what happens if a `KeyboardInterrupt` is during `(2)`?

It seems fundamentally impossible to guarantee resource cleanup in the presence of asyc exceptions without a way to mask them. Is there some facility for this, or do we rely on the [ostrich algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrich_algorithm)?

Comment: I think you pretty much have to install your own signal handler for Ctrl-C if you want to do this.

Answer (score 4):

This is what context managers are for.

```
with acquire() as x:
    do_something(x)
```

`acquire` returns an object whose type defines an `__enter__` method, which returns the value bound to `x`, and an `__exit__` method, which is executed at the end of the `with` statement regardless of how the statement is exited.

Comment: Can the `__exit__` method be interrupted if a further exception happens?

Comment: @DanielWagner My vague memory from way back when I wrote Python: exceptions that occur during `__exit__` interrupt the `__exit__` method as normal; the exception that prompted the `__exit__` block becomes the later exception's `__cause__`.

Comment: You do have to install a signal handler yourself, but the `__exit__` method provides a convenient scope for that: install the handler immediately upon entering the method, and restore the previous handler before exiting it.

Comment: Same question: Can the execution of a signal handler be interrupted by another signal?